# How do I correctly update the values of an object inside an array?

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

I have a `registerIntoQueue()` function that fills up an array with objects. Each object represents a person waiting in a **queue** to be served. The order of service is (**FIFO**), first in, first out. Find below my solidity code to add a person into the queue:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

uint peoplelBeforeMe = 0;

struct Queue {
    address customerAddress;
    uint peoplelBeforeMe;
    uint256 arrivalTime;
}

Queue[] private serviceQueue;

function registerIntoQueue() public {
    serviceQueue.push ( Queue(msg.sender, peoplelBeforeMe, block.timestamp ) );
    peoplelBeforeMe++;
}
```

The code above, having registered three people, would generate the below array of objects:

```
[customerAddress:0x446..9702, peoplelBeforeMe:0, arrivalTime:1653884369]
[customerAddress:0x786..2009, peoplelBeforeMe:1, arrivalTime:1653884469]
[customerAddress:0x589..5454, peoplelBeforeMe:2, arrivalTime:1653884569]
```

> Id like to bring your attention the value that the `peoplelBeforeMe` item in the
> object holds.

Following is the `removeFromQueue()` function. The person who joined the queue first (represented by `index[0]`) is always the one who gets served **first** and therefore gets **removed** from the `serviceQueue array`. In my code, this is represented by `serviceQueue.pop[]` as this removes the first item in the array, being in `index[0]`.

Find below my `removeFromQueue()` code:

```
function removeFromQueue() public {

    for(uint i = 0; i < serviceQueue.length - 1; i++){
        let numberOfPeopleBeforeMe = serviceQueue[i].peoplelBeforeMe;
        serviceQueue[i].peoplelBeforeMe = numberOfPeopleBeforeMe - 1;
        serviceQueue[i] = serviceQueue[i + 1];  
    }
    serviceQueue.pop();
}
```

The ideal outcome when `removeFromQueue()` is run would be:

```
[customerAddress:0x786..2009, peoplelBeforeMe:0, arrivalTime:1653884469]
[customerAddress:0x589..5454, peoplelBeforeMe:1, arrivalTime:1653884569]
```

> Kindly note how the `peoplelBeforeMe` was updated

My code in Remix, compiles perfectly well, and I am able to deploy it to the Ganache as a provider. The issue is, when I run the Dapp in the UI/front end I get the following error message:

[image: The error message I get]

It took me a while to figure out that `commenting out` or removing the follwing code from the `removeFromQueue()` function, resolves the issue:

```
  let numberOfPeopleBeforeMe = serviceQueue[i].peoplelBeforeMe;
  serviceQueue[i].peoplelBeforeMe = numberOfPeopleBeforeMe - 1;
```

making it:

```
 function removeFromQueue() public {

    for(uint i = 0; i < serviceQueue.length - 1; i++){
        serviceQueue[i] = serviceQueue[i + 1];  
    }
    serviceQueue.pop();
}
```

The code above erronously yeilds:

```
[customerAddress:0x786..2009, peoplelBeforeMe:1, arrivalTime:1653884469]
[customerAddress:0x589..5454, peoplelBeforeMe:2, arrivalTime:1653884569]
```

...because the `peoplelBeforeMe` doesn't reflect the number of people before each person in the queue.

How do I correctly update the `peoplelBeforeMe` item without it causing any issues and with minimum gasfees?

Comment: pop() remove and returns the **last** element of the array - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=pop#array-members

Comment: Forgot to add: what you're trying to implement can be seen as a *linked list* - what is more important in your use case, the absolute value of peopleBeforeMe (I'd make it a function then, instead of updating the whole dataset) or the order of elements (then peopleBeforeMe could be replace by 'customerAddressBeforeMe')?

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth thanks for the prompt response, any chance you can demonstrate in code?